# How to make sure URLConnection is valid and will successfully connect in Java?

Tags: java, url, connection

how can you ensure URL you receive from users is a valid url and not just a http://nothing.com

my code looks like this:

```
String urlFromUser = getUrlFromUser(); // might return: http://www.notARealSite.com
URL url = new URL(urlFromUser);

// this might fail
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

and try catch is not enough, i want to make sure the site is real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use:

```
if(new InetSocketAddress(urlFromUser, 80).isUnresolved()) {
    // URL is a not a valid server address
}
else {
    // URL is valid
}
```

Comment: This is not sufficient.  It only checks that the URL's domain can be resolved to an IP address.  It doesn't check that the site is reachable, that it is running a webserver (HTTP or HTTPS), that the URL path is meaningful, etcetera.  The only real way to validate a URL is to attempt to retrieve it.  (And even then there can be complications; e.g. you may need to "login" to retrieve it.)

Comment: that is exactly what i looked for, to check if the site is valid and real, and not a made-up url, i know how to do open connection and actually connect to the site, error connecting to site, does not mean it is invalid